# Require.js problema al cargar un módulo

Tags: requirejs

Tengo un problema a la hora de cargar un módulo.

En **main.js** tengo:

```
// Filename: main.js
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery'    
  }
});
require([
  'app'
], function(App){
  App.init();
});
```

En **app.js**:

```
// Filename: app.js
define([
  'jquery'
], function($){

  var initialize = function(){
    alert(1);    
  }
  return {
    init: initialize
  };
});
```

El error es:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property `init` of `undefined`.

Comment: Puede ser que tu archivo `app.js` no se este cargando de la manera correcta, basicamente porque no lo encuentra, revisa bien en las peticiones del navegador si app.js se carga correctamente. Agrega un `baseUrl` a tu archivo `main.js`, por ejemplo algo como `baseUrl: '/js'` para indicarle a requirejs que cargue los archivos con base en ese path. Comparte el encarpetado y estructurado de tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

intenta de esta manera:

```
// Filename: app.js
define([
  'jquery'
], function($){

    var myModule = {
        init:function(){
            alert(1); 
        }
    }

    return myModule;
});
```

...y después le vas a proximando hacia la implementación previa